# css overridden by Chrome

Tags: css, google-chrome, chromium

can anyone explain this please?

[image: Chrome developer tool]

So the tool shows that the rgb(250,255,189) is superceded by the salmon (because the rgb is crossed out) YET despite salmon being the one showing, the summary row and the actual colour displayed is the rgb(250...) colour!

It's bad enough that auto-fill css seems to override anything we might want to style but even the Chrome developer tool doesn't seem to know how to interpret it....

I have a rule that is more specific than the user agent stylesheet, the same definition but with the class specified too, yet Chrome's autofill is still winning - any solution?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try `-webkit-autofill`

```css
input {
  background-color: white;
}
/*input:focus {
  background-color: grey
}*/
input:-webkit-autofill{
  transition: background-color 1s ease-in-out 5000s;
}

body {
  background: #333;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  font-size: 2em;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputFirst">First Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputFirst">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputLast">Last Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputLast">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="exampleInputEmail">Email Address</label>
    <input type="email" class="form-control input-lg" id="exampleInputEmail">
  </div>
 
  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg btn-block">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: you might just be able to see in the picture - my salmon colour does indeed use the -webkit-autofill pseudo selector in CSS, the important part of your answer is the transition I think.
And it almost works. My CSS also has a background-colour of grey when input gets focus (:focus). The problem i have now is that the field I am on when I hit the autofill keeps it's grey background even when I move off it. How can I fix that?
thanks

Comment: Sorry, I have no better idea. You may need a css rule stronger than  '-webkit-autofill' and weaker than input:focus. I'm afraid it's not possible to use "background-color" or "transition" or other simple css to get this work. Tell me if you find a solution, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually having a problem with `webkit-autofill`. But that color should only appeear if Chrome is auto filling your input fields. Which probably it is.

Take a look at this quote from MDN:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:-webkit-autofill

> The user agent style sheets of many browsers use !important in their :-
>   webkit-autofill style declarations, making them non-overrideable by webpages without resorting to JavaScript hacks.

So I guess this could be a problem. Did you try checking out the page in incognito window? So that the Chromes auto-fill feature doesn't turn on?

Comment: yep it is auto-fill. That's the question. Why does it ignore my site style which is more specific (and uses the -webkit-autofill pseudo selector). Seems like it is a transition thing as per King Rui's answer below because my element is an input with a certain class and has been autofilled. So my CSS of input.class:-webkit-autofill{background-colour:salmon !important} should be dominant (and indeed Chrome developer tools suggest it is) but I think a transition has superceded it.

Comment: 'transition' works because it 'delay' the background color change of browser webkit-autofill style. If you wait for enough long time (5000s of this code), you will see the background color changed by browser, but no one will wait for such a long time ^_^.